# Output text in a stored procedure using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to output the text (contents) in a stored procedure using a query? I want to have a query that I can run and just input the name of the stored proc instead of navigating to it.

There are literally hundreds of stored procs I have to navigate to, right click and select Modify and I would like an easier way to see the contents of the stored proc.

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Maybe something similar to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.procedures  
WHERE name = 'stored_procedure_name'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do that, You can try one of the following:

```
EXEC sp_helptext 'YourProcedure'
```

Which gives you the one row per line of the stored procedure, Or

```
SELECT definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourProcedure')
```

Which gives you a single row with all of the stored procedure definition.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Your first example is **exactly** what I was looking for and I can easily copy and paste the Results if I need to!